# Handling database errors for API used by JavaScript

Tags: php, error-handling

I have several API-s for performing some actions on my site with JSON response. Since PHP files are only accessed via AJAX, i want to change the way errors are shown.

Currently if error occurs it does something like this

```
die('Getting Result Error: (' . $this->sql->errno . ') ' . $this->sql->error);
```

So this will never get to the user (site owner) because JavaScript is handling JSON response

I'm thinking about switching to [error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)

```
error_log('Getting Result Error: (' . $this->sql->errno . ') ' . $this->sql->error, 0);
```

Is this a better practice? What do you recommend.

Also I was thinking about just doing this

```
error_log('Getting Result Error: (' . $this->sql->errno . ') ' . $this->sql->error, 0);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$arr = array("status"=>'error');
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

So i notify my script something is wrong and user will se this error, and owner of site sees it in error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`error_log` has the option to send a message to a nominated email address:

```
$admin='admin@example.com';
$headers= …;        //  as per mail() function
error_log($error,1,$admin,$headers);
```

This will notify the administrator.

I presume you would probably follow this with some sort of message back to the user.